# How to change text style in bibliography style?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am using this package for my bibliography:

```
\usepackage{bibgerm}
\bibliographystyle{gerunsrt}
```

This is the result:

[image]

I don't want the authors to appear in `small capitals` text style. How can I change this?

Comment: Making a copy of the style, rename it, change the copyright, change the relevant part to not use small caps, save the file and use the new file instead.

Comment: With the modern biblatex system, it would be just a single line in the preamble.

Comment: Ok, but where can I find the style? I am on Mac with MacTex. What is the folder path?

Comment: I would siggest to take a look at http://golatex.de/wichtige-hinweise-erstellung-von-literaturverzeichnissen-t11964.html first.

Comment: I suppose the package is `germbib`, not `bibgerman`. In any case the germbib package contains `gerunsrt.bst`. It is to be found in `texmf/bibtex/bst/germbib/`.

Comment: No, the package is `bibgerm`

Comment: It doesn't really matter what it is called. It is deprecated for a long time. Its successor is `babelbib` to get a language dependent bibliography. With `biblatex`, you don't need any extra packages. It is all in one. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Comment: Benjamin1956, try the command line.  The filename is the `\usepackage` parameter plus `.sty`, so  `kpsewhich bibgerm.sty` should do the trick.

Comment: Is there any news here?